# Accessing Multiple DML Exception Errors from Validation Rules

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule, exception, dmlexception

I've been looking around but haven't found a good explicit answer for handling when multiple validation rules fail simultaneously.

Let's say I have a custom object called MyObject__c with two different validation rules.

The first validation rule will be on a number field called SampleQuantity__c.
If SampleQuantity__c < 10, it'll throw an exception saying "Your minimum quantity is 10"

The second validation rule will be on another number field called SampleHoursSpent__c. 
If SampleHoursSpent__c > 40, it'll throw an exception saying "You have spent the maximum number of hours per week. Please update overtime field."

I'll have something similar to the following when I update my record.

```
List<MyObject__c> myObjList = getObjects();
try {
      update myObjList;
} catch (DMLException ex) {
    /* this line will get both error messages if both of them fail simultaneously */
    ApexPages.addMessages(ex);

    /* however, if i try to get the number of dml exceptions with a loop,
     * there is only 1 
     */
    for (Integer i = 0; i < ex.getNumDml(); i++) {
        System.debug(ex.getDmlMessage(i));
    }
}
```

Why can I not see all the DML messages when I try to iterate over them, yet I am able to get them through ApexPages? Shouldn't the behavior be the same?

I've also tried browsing SFDC known issues, but couldn't find something that is related to this issue.

Comment: how many records you are updating, single or multiple?

Comment: @Justin If one of these answers [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 3):

[@Santanu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/33230/santanu-boral) makes a great point that I would like to expand on a bit. Note in the `Database.SaveResult` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult) that there is a `getErrors()` method that returns a `List<Database.Error>`. This collection is what you need to iterate through.

```
Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(record, /*allOrNone*/ false);
for (Database.Error error : result.getErrors())
{
    // all results will be here
}
```

Also note that there are different `*Result` objects depending on your `DML` operation, but they all share this method.

```
Database.UpsertResult result = Database.upsert(record, false);
Database.DeleteResult result = Database.delete(record, false);
Database.UndeleteResult result = Database.undelete(record, false);
Database.EmptyRecycleBinResult result = Database.emptyRecycleBin(record, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding. This was a very helpful complement to Santanu's answer.

Comment: @Justin related reading: [Do the *Result objects in Database have a common ancestor?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/125880/do-the-result-objects-in-database-have-a-common-ancestor)

Answer (score 2):

I can presume you are doing multiple updates at a time.

If it is a single update, the first validation error it get captured in `catch` block and it will not execute again, because of `update` statement.

I think if you use `Database.update()` you will get all the DML messages for multiple records which are getting failed.

`Database.SaveResult[] update(sObject[] recordsToUpdate, Boolean allOrNone)`

> **allOrNone**
>   Type: Boolean
>
> The optional allOrNone parameter specifies whether the operation allows partial success. If you specify false for this parameter and a record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed. This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which records succeeded, which failed, and why.

Comment: I am updating a list of records all at once. Thank you for your help. I'll give it a try and let you know after.