# Is there a parent class/interface for DML Result classes?

Tags: apex, dml, saveresult

I have a generic method that performs DML operations. I want it to return a result list, and I am wondering if there is a parent class/interface that DML Result classes derive from.

All DML Result classes such as SaveResult and DeleteResult seem to share the same methods, which makes me curious about the existence of a higher order.

Comment: I believe that SF is written on Java. Classes you are talking about are inherited from common interface, that's why they have similar methods. But it's internal part of SF framework and you're not suppose to see it. Of course if you are not trying to work in SF directly, or you want to clone whole PAAS.

Comment: I believe you are asking a question already asked on SFSE by [sfdcfox](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox): [Do the \*Result objects in Database have a common ancestor?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/125880/do-the-result-objects-in-database-have-a-common-ancestor)