# Does Wrapper Class serve one purpose only?

Tags: apex, class, wrapper-class

Does it only come handy in a situation "display a table of records with a check box and then process only the records that are selected".

Because I have searched and found every website displaying this in its example.

Is wrapper class used other than the above scenario as well?

Comment: You can use wrapper class to serialize/deserialize from JSON or so. Basically, wrapper class is still a **class**, so you can use it in any way that you want, which is applicable for classes

Comment: Likely duplicate: [Purpose of an inner class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/138355/2995)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Agree there is some overlap and I nearly linked to that post because I was going to mention that inner classes are a good way to go for these Wrapper classes. But this question seems to me about a pattern name (that gets overused IMHO) and not about inner classes.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at what Google has to say, **Wrapper** is an alternative name for both these patterns:

- [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)
- [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

So the examples that focus on adding a checkbox might be better labelled as **Decorator** classes not **Wrapper** classes to be more specific and so clearer.

An example that say takes two different types of SObject and presents them in one table is acting as an **Adapter** (and is still a legitimate use of the term **Wrapper**).

IMHO the term should not be used where an object (or objects) are not being "wrapped". So, for example, the classes you might use for JSON serialization/deserialization would be better termed **POAO** (Plain Old Apex Object) following the term that started in Java with [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object), but unfortunately POAO is not a term that has gathered any momentum.

Another **POAO** example is where you need a method to return multiple values of differing types: the method returns an instance of the POAO class.

Keep in mind that Apex is a fairly/fully [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) programming language that you can use to build any lines of code that help you solve your business problem. Patterns like **Wrapper** are just off the-shelf examples of pieces of code you can build with names that help developers quickly understand what is going on. There are lots of [patterns to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) to be inspired by.

Answer (score 5):

I believe not.

Wrapper class is a custom table in my belief. Though checkbox is a great example of it. But above it, I have been using Wrapper Classes beyond it's scope.

Suppose there is a Custom object you fetched using SOQL query, than you want to bind another field to it which is not statically stored in the DB but is dynamic in the code.

As the checkbox example states, one can bind the checkbox value(true/false) to the record.

> A wrapper class is a custom object defined by programmer wherein he
>   defines the wrapper class properties. Consider a custom object in
>   salesforce, what do you have in it? fields right? different fields of
>   different data types. Similarly wrapper class is a custom class which
>   has different data types or properties as per requirement. We can wrap
>   different objects types or any other types in a wrapper class.

Comment: I've used Wrapper Classes on the Event Object too, Polymorphic fields were the bane of my existence once upon a time. Wrapper classes helped me attach an Event with the Contact in the `WhoId` field in a Visualforce Page.

Comment: +1, I would also like to add that, wrapper class plays a very handy role when you're writing a REST webservice in apex. You create your wrapper class as per JSON format which you'll be consuming.