# Does defining and referencing a public inner class takes up more character count in salesforce?

Tags: apex

Class :

```
public class test2 {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String fetchHTML(){
        return '';
    }

    public class happyDays{
        public void happyDaysMethod(){

        }
    }

}
```

Now if I have to refer `happyDays` class from some other class I will have to refer it like this:

```
public class Test1{

   public test2.happyDays objTest4321 {get; set;}
}
```

as `public happyDays objTest4321 {get; set;}` will give compilation error.

Does this mean defining inner class may increase apex character count as we are using ParentClassReference.InnerClass, so ParentClassReference name character count increases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but inner classes can have benefits that far, far outweigh the normally insignificant factor of the Apex character count.

See e.g. [Purpose of an inner class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138355/purpose-of-an-inner-class).

Comment: yes I do understand the purpose of it, was just curious to check if Apex character count is included or not. Thanks

Comment: @NagendraSingh One really easy way to drastically reduce character count is to replace any instances of four spaces (or whatever you prefer to use for indentation) with actual tabs. In a typical project, I've seen as much as a 25% reduction in Apex character count. The increased limit (6MB) means you'll rarely need this, but if you want a quick way to drop the count, this is definitely low-hanging fruit you can reach for.